# Django can't overwrite logout view

Tags: django, authentication, view, logout, overwrite

I use `django.contrib.auth.urls` to logout user. I want and I have view logout but I don't know why when I go to accounts/logout/ url django does not use mine, but default view for logout.

```
from django.urls import path, include
import django.contrib.auth.urls

from . import views
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [

path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('accounts/sign_up/', views.sign_up, name="sign-up"),
path('accounts/logout/', views.logout_view, name="logout"),


]


def logout_view(request):
print(request.user)
context = {'user2': request.user}
logout(request)
return render(request, 'accounts/logged_out.html', context)
```

Comment: Since `path('accouts/',...)` is ordered *first* it will fire the `logout` view in the `django.contrib.auth.urls` module.

Answer (score 1):

Since `path('accouts/', …)` is ordered *first* it will fire the [**`logout/`** path [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L11) in the `django.contrib.auth.urls` module.

If you change the order, it will thus first match with the `logout_view` and fire that view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/sign_up/', views.sign_up, name='sign-up'),
]
```